# Ruby on Rails - Single Sign Up and Login Form for Two Different User Types and handling the Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm currently pretty new to Ruby on Rails, but right now I'm trying to set up a simple platform to create events, manage those events, and purchase tickets to those events. I have two different user types:

```
Manager:
has_many: events

(with params):
email
password
organization_name


Fan:
has_many: tickets

(with params):
email
password
name
cell_phone
```

I have two different partials containing sign-up forms for both Managers and Fans. My thought process right now is to have a param called @is_manager in the session that allows my sign-up form to dynamically hide/reveal the partials and to handle logic in the controller.

The sign-in form for both models will be identical, as they can both login using their emails and passwords. My current thought for this is to either include an additional checkbox which filters attempted logins to either the Fan or Manager database, or to require emails to be unique across both databases.

I've looked at a large number of other stack overflow questions, and have looked into Devise (which I was cautioned against while I still don't have a strong handling of Ruby on Rails), as well as some JQuery solutions to dynamically changing this session param, but I haven't found a solution which I feel applies well to me.

Thoughts?

(My current sign-up form code is something like below:)

```
<h1>Signup</h1>

  <h3>Are you a manager?</h3>
  <%= link_to_function "Yes", "magic_javascript_function" %>
  <%= link_to_function "No", "magic_javascript_function" %>

<%= form_for :session, url: signup_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'manager_signup', :f => f if @is_manager %>
  <%= render 'user_signup', :f => f unless @is_manager %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've used Devise and another gem called CanCan (aka CanCanCan) that work well together. You can assign roles to users, so that they are managers, fans, or even both. Then you would only have one model and one sign in/up form. Bit of a learning curve, but I well worth it :)

Comment: Devise and CanCan have easily been the two most frequent gems I've seen in my overflow-adventures for this problem, but I've also read that using Devise is difficult without a semi-deep understanding of RoR, which is why I've been trying to cobble together a different solution :)

How much of my existing code (and I know this is hard to tell without seeing the code itself) do you think I'll need to scrap with regards to the two models though if I were to switch over? And will I be able to keep the other models (Events, Tickets) without change?

But thanks for the comment! =D

Answer (score 1):

If your new to RoR I highly advise going to The Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl's [railstutorial.org](http://www.railstutorial.org).

I recomend this tutorial because he shows how to create a user model with login sessions etc. without using devise or cancan and this gives excelent insight into what those programs are used for and how they work so you can use them later.

In regards to your specific case I would argue this: What if a member who has only acted as a manger wants to go to another managers event. Would he then need a separate fan account. Alternatively what if a member who has only been a fan wants to organize a local event for his garage band.

See where I am going with this. It might be best for a login/signup page to be agnostic towards these roles.

Where you could use these roles however is in you relationships 
here you could do something like this

```
User.rb
    has_many: events
    has_many: tickets

Event.rb
    belongs_to: manager, class_name: "User"
    has_many: tickets

Ticket.rb
    belongs_to: event
    belongs_to: fan, class_name: "User"
```

Check the [belongs_to api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) if it this gives you trouble you may need to explicitly set the foreign key.